# Does the Uehling potential have any observable effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, pair-production

Uehling potential is the correction made to the coulomb potential due to vacuum polarization (electron-positron pair creation and annihilation). How big is this correction compared to the coulomb potential (0.01% for example), and can the change it makes to the coulomb potential have a significant observable effect? If so, where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The [Uehling potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uehling_potential) due to [vacuum polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_polarization) by virtual electron-positron pairs is the dominant contribution — 205.0073 meV — to the [Lamb shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_shift) between the $2P_{1/2}$ and $2S_{1/2}$ states of muonic hydrogen. (See equation (15) [here](https://www.fuw.edu.pl/~krp/papers/pohl.pdf).)

Muonic hydrogen is a bound state of a proton and a muon. Since a muon is more massive than an electron, the muon orbitals lie closer to the proton than electron orbitals do. The Uehling potential is significant only at short distances where the electrostatic field of the proton is intense, so tightly bound muonic hydrogen is better able to probe the region close to the proton.

The Lamb shift is a QED effect due to virtual particles; the $2S_{1/2}$ and $2P_{1/2}$ states have exactly the same energy if you simply calculate energy levels using the Dirac equation. The Lamb shift in electronic hydrogen is mainly due to the self-energy of the electron (i.e., its interaction with virtual photons). By contrast, the Lamb shift in muonic hydrogen is mainly due to vacuum polarization (i.e., the muon interacting indirectly via virtual photons with virtual electrons and positrons).

The Lamb shift in muonic hydrogen was measured in 2010 by Pohl et. al. There are other contributions coming from the finite size of the proton, so this experiment constituted a measurement of the proton radius. However, it got a result that differed from other techniques for measuring the proton size, and this has led to the [proton radius puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_radius_puzzle).

When two charges are separated by the reduced Compton wavelength of an electron, their potential energy is greater than what Coulomb's Law predicts by a factor of 1.0000556435. When their separation is only one tenth of this, the correction factor grows to 1.00172446. You can obtain these numbers by numerically evaluating the integral in the Coulomb-plus-Uehling-correction potential of a charge $q$,

$$V(r)=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}\left(1+\frac{2\alpha}{3\pi}\int_1^\infty dx\,e^{-2x r/\lambda_{e,r}}\frac{2x^2+1}{2x^4}\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)$$

Here $\alpha$ is the fine structure constrant and $\lambda_{e,r}=\hbar/m_e c$ is the reduced Compton wavelength of the electron.

In electronic hydrogen, the radius of the ground-state orbital (the Bohr radius) is about 137 times larger than the reduced Compton wavelength of the electron. (This is the reciprocal of the fine structure constant.) At this distance, the Uehling correction is negligible because of the exponential factor in the integral. But in muonic hydrogen, this radius is reduced by a factor of about 207, the ratio of the muon mass to the electron mass. This makes the muonic ground-state orbital radius just 0.663 of the reduced Compton wavelength of the electron, and makes the Uehling correction measurable.

Comment: Do they have any effect on the coulomb force on a charged particle (which is produces by other charged particles around it)?

Comment: For example the coulomb force between two electrons.

Comment: Yes, the Uehling potential makes the Coulomb force differ slightly from $1/r^2$ at distances less than one electron Compton wavelength.

Comment: Thanks. Does this virtual electron-positron pairs appear in an atomic nucleus too? If so, is their effect larger there due to the great electrical field intensity, and so can they affect the radioactive decay process?

Comment: I have never seen this discussed. I see no reason why there would not be virtual electron-positron pairs inside the nucleus. The Uehling potential should slightly modify the electrostatic interaction between protons. I suppose it might slightly affect radioactive decay as a consequence.

Comment: Let me ask another question. You mentioned that the Uehling potential makes a noticeable change to the Coulomb potential only at distances less than one Compton wavelength. In the Wikipedia page you referenced (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_shift) it's told that "The fluctuation in the electric and magnetic fields associated with the QED vacuum perturbs the electric potential of the atomic nucleus. This perturbation causes a fluctuation in the position of the electron, which explains the energy shift". So, how come the electron's position can change substantially at a larger distance?

Comment: And also, does this electron position fluctuation and lamb shift occur in every atom, or only in muonic hydrogen? The Wikipedia page says that the lamb shift occurs in the hydrogen atom, and doesn't restrict it to muonic hydrogen.

Comment: Vacuum polarization caused by electron-positron pairs occurs everywhere and affects all atoms and other systems of interacting charged particles, such as in colliders. There is nothing special about muonic hydrogen except that the effect of the Uehling potential is easier to measure in this system because it is larger than in, say, normal hydrogen. The Uehling effect is only one of several contributions to the Lamb shift. In normal hydrogen, I’m pretty sure that other QED effects are more important, and I don’t think the Uehling effect is measurable in normal H with current technology.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean there are other QED effects other than the Uehling potential, that modify the electric potential associated with the nucleus? Do these effects perturb the positions of electrons in the atom (as suggested by the "lamb shift" Wikipedia page? Could you please list some of these QED effects so can read about them?

Comment: Yes, the self-energy correction from the electron emitting and absorbing a virtual photon is more important than Uehling’s vacuum polarization correction. See page 8 of http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~srk/Ay126/Lectures/Lecture5/Lecture%202-3.pdf. I assume that both effects perturb the electron’s mean radial position, but I haven’t seen this calculation.

Comment: So does such a change in electron positions due to vacuum fluctuations, and energy level shifts exist in all atoms (say calcium for example)? And, which of these QED effects are produced by virtual electron-positron pairs (only the Uehling potential, or all of the QED effects leading to vacuum energy and field fluctuation)?

Comment: These effects exist in all atoms. Only the Uehling potential involves electron-positron pairs at the lowest (one-loop) level of approximation, but all effects involve electron-positron pairs at higher levels (two or more loops) of approximation. Is there some reason that you have not marked my answer as accepted after a month?

Comment: of course, sorry that I market it as accepted late, I didn't think you cared. Your answer is perfect.

Comment: I have two more questions! First, you previously told me that the Uehling correction is only noticeable within a Compton wavelength of an electron. I thought you meant that a particle should be within a Compton wavelength from the electron in order to feel the Uehling correction of the field of that electron. But, in the Caltech presentation you referenced, it's said, if an electron is placed in an E field, the corrections to that E field is notable within a Compton wavelength of electron. Does this mean that the Uehling potential will always alter an electrons's trajectory in an E field?

Comment: Second, the lamb shift is discussed for H-type atoms. The energy shift might or might not exist in other atoms, but, shouldn't the "smearing"-type changes in the electron's position be present in any atom? Basically, what determines how much the electron gets "smeared"?

Comment: The Uehling potential is a correction to the field of a point charge, not a correction to an arbitrary field. However, QED corrections do occur in any field. For example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Heisenberg_Lagrangian

Comment: The wavefunction for an electron is always “smeared”. That’s just how quantum mechanics works. QED corrections simply slightly change the wavefunction. For example, with the Uehling potential you can use perturbation theory to calculate the change in observables.

Comment: StackExchange is telling me that comments are not for extended discussions, so please ask further questions as new posted questions. Thanks.

Comment: I did, please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/476496/what-parameters-determine-the-amount-of-uehling-potential-and-self-energy-correc