# What parameters determine the amount of Uehling potential and self-energy correction effects?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, pair-production, lamb-shift

Uehling potential correction and electron self-energy correction are the two most important factors contributing to the lamb shift in the hydrogen atom, by "smearing" the wavefunction of the electron. What parameter(s) determine "how much" this smearing of the wavefunction is?

Comment: You would have to mathematically define what you mean by “smearing” of a wavefunction. I would describe all wavefunctions as smeared even without any QED corrections.

Comment: Electron self-energy correction and Uehling correction change the wavefunction of the electron with regard to the case we are not considering QED effects. I mean the amount of that change. You mentioned that these are the major contributors to the lamb shift. My question is, what determines how largely these QED effects affect the wavefunction of the electron, electrons velocity, strength of the electric field the electron is sensing, electric potential, or what?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_shift has a derivation of the fluctuation in the position of the electron.

Comment: The fine-structure constant is the relevant parameter which determines the fluctuation in the position compared with the Compton wavelength.

Comment: As far as I know, the fine structure constant is always equal to 1/137, so the fluctuation in the position should be equal for all electrons in all atoms. Is this true?

Comment: Also, is the fine structure constant the only important parameter determining the amount of position fluctuation? I had heard that the electron's energy (velocity) is effective on the self-energy correction. Isn't the electric potential/field the particle senses effective on the Uehling-induced position fluctuation?

Comment: The Wikipedia derivation is for hydrogen. I would guess that for other atoms there would be a dependence on $Z$ but I am not sure.

Comment: StackExchange has told me to avoid extended discussions in comments, so I’m done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92983/discussion-between-ali-lavasani-and-g-smith).