# About calculating a contribution to Lamb-shift through Uehling's potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, hydrogen

Well, I've been calculating Uelingh potential using the amplitude of the QED vacuum polarization. Now, I'd like to go on and calculate the Lamb-shift. And here is my question: How can I do that? Should I use this expression of the correted Coulomb's potential in Dirac's equation? Or are there another way to do that?

Comment: Related: [Does the Uehling potential have any observable effect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/468224/does-the-uehling-potential-have-any-observable-effect) See eq. (15) in the paper that the answer links to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the Uehling correction to the Coulomb potential as a perturbation. Use first-order time-independent perturbation theory to calculate the energy shift in the two energy levels involved in the Lamb shift.